# Trying to download multiple files from the same dropdown menu - Python Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having issues attempting to download two separate files from the same dropdown menu on a website using Selenium Chromedriver.

I have code to click on both of the links, but it only acknowledges the first link; the second file does not get downloaded. I know that when I am not using the webdriver I can have multiple downloads going at once, so maybe the issue is that the chromedriver will only allow one download at a time? I'm not sure. I have tried adding an implicit wait between the spreadsheet and the shapefile clicks, but that ends up making the code download only the shapefile and not the spreadsheet. Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

### Assign chrome driver path and setup driver ###
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\johns\Documents\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

### Open Chrome and go to webpage for file ###
driver.get("http://data-ocpagis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/osceolataxparcels09012020?geometry=-82.957%2C27.570%2C-79.562%2C28.419")
### Wait because ARCGISOL webpages take a little to fully load ###
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

### Click Download dropdown button ###
DownloadButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ember64"]/button""")
DownloadButton.click()

### Click link for csv download ###
CSVLink = driver.find_element_by_id("ember66")
CSVLink.click()

### Click link for shapefile download ###
ShapefileLink = driver.find_element_by_id("ember68")
ShapefileLink.click()
```

With this code, the CSV file button is clicked and the file is downloaded, but nothing happens after that. I need this code to click and download both the spreadsheet and shapefile from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing the page between downloads:

```
driver.refresh();
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! I just had to re-insert the dropdown button click before the second download and it worked like a charm!

Comment: A question: I have to write this script for 11 different websites, some websites I have to download 10+ files from. Will it be necessary to always have to refresh and re-click my dropdown buttons in order to download multiple files? That seems like it would be a little more work than necessary, but I am still very new with selenium.

Comment: Well, I guess that is the way your site works. Maybe you could talk to your developers (if you are using selenium to automate tests - that's just my assumption) and they could change the way your page works.

Comment: I'm just actually using selenium to gather data from multiple different county property appraiser websites, not for any testing purposes. But I'm sure I can figure out the best way to smooth out the process. I have accepted and upvoted your answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using a library such as BeautifulSoup to extract the download links out of the HTML.

After visiting the website you could grab the page source and create a soup out of it. We can then search for the download-items and grab the urls.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

req = get('http://data-ocpagis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/osceolataxparcels09012020?geometry=-82.957%2C27.570%2C-79.562%2C28.419&selectedAttribute=AREA')
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(req.content), 'html.parser')
files = soup.find_all('a', class_='download-item')

for file in files:
    print(file['href'])
```

Comment: I have not used beautiful soup before, but it definitely seems useful. I know that the normal intent for selenium is webpage testing but I'm simply using it to scrape different files from websites that I need. Would you recommend using Beautiful Soup instead of selenium for this purpose?

Comment: @ParkerJohnson If you are just scraping, Beautiful Soup might be a good fit for you. It doesn't require a web driver installed for the browser.

Comment: I would definitely recommend beautifulsoup for it. Selenium is a great tool but for smaller jobs scraping can be done much easier and more efficient when just using a html parser.